# How to call a jquery function inside a loop by declaring it outside the loop

Tags: jquery, jslint

I am new to jquery and stuck in a problem and need help from experts.

here is my code

```
 for (val in list) {
    var result = $.grep(node, function(e){
          return e.id === list[val].Id;
    });
    if (result === 0)
     // do something
}
```

When i try to pass JSLint on my I got this error

```
#1 Don't make functions within a loop.
```

I know the problem that i am making a function in the jquery grep function
But i am stuck as how to move my function out side the loop assign it to a variable and then call it. As my function is talking an argument e. I have tried it like this

```
var Visible = function (e, list, val) {return e.id === list[val].Id;}; 

for (val in list) {
   var result = $.grep(node, Visible(e, list, val));
}
```

but now jslint is giving an error that

```
 #1 'e' was used before it was defined.
    var result = $.grep(node, Visible(e)); // Line 125, Pos 69
```

//--------------------------------------------------------------------

here is the data

```
node: Array[5]
  0: HTMLTableRowElement
  1: HTMLTableRowElement 
  2: HTMLTableRowElement
  3: HTMLTableRowElement

list: Array[5]
  0: Object
    0: "cc"
    1: "ss"
    Id: "000"
  1: Object
  2: Object
```

Now I am finding that for which element of the the list an html element exist. If for any element in the list and htmlelement does not exist then i r=create one i am checking it by **result === 0**
  what can be the solution to this problem. Any help will be appreciated
thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: what is `node`? `$.grep` will return an array, so it can never equal zero. Help to understand objective of your code

Comment: You could use jQuery's `$.each` to work around this warning.

Comment: node is basically some array of html elements

Comment: okay what i am doing is that i am finding that the hmlt element elreay exist or not . node contains html element and i am comparing the ids in the list one by one with all the node elements ids

Comment: If you could provide examples of the values of `node` and `list`, we might be able to suggest a different approach.

Comment: @FelixKling added an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A far simpler approach is to simply create an ID selector and check if it exists:

```
for (val in list) {    
    if( $('#'+list[val].Id).length){
        /* element exists in page*/
    }       
}
```

To look within `node` as collection of elements only can use `filter()` method

```
var $node=$(node);
for (val in list) {    
     if( $node.filter('#'+list[val].Id).length){
            /* element exists in node*/
     }       
 }
```

Comment: thanks alot for your response but the issue is that my html element might be hidden that is its parent might have display : none

Comment: OK.. easily check by adding `:visible` selector. Would really help if instead of trying to patch your code togethe you give full explanation of what you are trying to do. Could write `if( $('#'+list[val].Id).is(':visible'))` for example. Solution you need is likley very straighforward...just not sure what you need

Comment: thanks alot. How it can be check using visible selecter can you please explain a little bit. Sure I will keep your this point in my mind :)

Comment: $('#'+list[val].Id).is(':visible')) so will this statement will check both visible and hidden?

Comment: can't explain what I don't understand... you should start with providing full details of objective... forget `node` and explain from start

Comment: okay so this is what i want. I have a table and i am updating it periodically. I have a list which has data used to make row of the table. so after every 10 sec i got a data. and some how I get the html elements for all the rows. Now i loop through my list of data and find that for which data a row(html element) exist and for which data row does not exist. if it does not exist then i create one row. Also there is a chance that some of the rows of table a hidden you can say at some other page. so they must not be added twice. I am using datatable.net library

Comment: make more sense to merge the data removing duplicates, look at `$.inArray` to check if a value is in an array. Can use `$.grep` on the new data also

Comment: several other factors is that if you have any pagination in table, or hidden filters, elements will be stored in datatables data..not in page so you would really want to be comparing to that data, not what's in page

Comment: I suggest to create question reflective of using datatables and provide live sample of data, and code you are currentyly trying to use simply to do update( without any of your filtering code above). Explain details as they pertain to your use of `datatables`

Comment: Sure i will write an other question reflecting my orignal problem

Answer (score 2):

When you write `Visible(e)` you call function visible with argument `e`. This is not what you want. You want to give the function itself to `.grep()`. So try fixing it like this:

```
var result = $.grep(node, Visible);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a function to `$.grep`. But `Visible(e, list, val)` is trying to **call** the function and passing the return value to `$.grep` (which is either `true` or `false`). At that moment, `e` is not defined yet (it's an argument which `$.grep` is supposed to pass to the callback).

Instead, you have to create a function which *returns* a function that does the comparison:

```
function createCallback(id) {
    return function(e) {
        return e.id === id}; 
    };
}

for (val in list) {
   var result = $.grep(node, createCallback(list[val].Id));
}
```

---

That said, creating functions in a loop is ok as long as those functions are called before the next iteration of the loop, but JSLint is very picky.

---

A better solution could to remove all elements from the array for which elements already exist:

```
$.map(list, function() {
    return $('#' + this.Id).length === 1 ? null : this;
}).each(function() {
    // create and append element here
    // e.g.
    $('<div />', {id: this.Id}).appendTo('#container');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need jQuery for this at all. Just use two loops, and check what you want:

```
for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
    var found = false;    
    for (var j=0; j<node.length; j++) {    
        if(list[i].id == node[j].Id) {
            // We have found such element in node!
            found = true;
            break; 
        }
    }     
    if(!found) {
        // we did not find such element in node
    }
}
```

I suggest you to understand how basic Javascript loops work, and only after that use jQuery functions for such tasks. It will help you.